# Problema con ResultSet En Java / MySQL: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, jdbc

Muy buenas, compañeros.

Estoy teniendo un cierto problema que aun no logro identificar bien en Java con un ResultSet que uso, me arroja un error de

> java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

y aun no logro identificar por qué.

Mi código es muy simple, sólo genero un archivo plano con datos provenientes de una Base de datos los cuales están delimitados por "|", pero, a la hora de llenar el archivo con los datos mediante un ResultSet este me indica este error y no realiza la función. Aquí les añado el código que he usado para este aplicativo:

**Codigo de evento del botón crear archivo**

```
    ModelCartas_Laborales obj = new ModelCartas_Laborales();
    ControllerCartas_Laborales obj2 = new ControllerCartas_Laborales();
    ControllerEscribir archivo = new ControllerEscribir();
    obj.setLapso(jTextField1.getText());
    try {
        archivo.crearArchivo(obj2.obtenerCartas(obj));
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CLFormulario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

**Código de la clase Control**

```
public class ControllerCartas_Laborales {
Conexion con = new Conexion();
String sql;

public ResultSet obtenerCartas(ModelCartas_Laborales obj){
    ResultSet rs;
    sql = "SELECT DISTINCT 'NULL' AS ID, 'CC' AS COD_DOC, tr.CODIGO AS EMPLEADO, ct.CODIGO AS CONTRATO, ct.ID_EMP AS EMPRESA,\n" +
    "   tr.`DESCRIPCION` AS  NOMBRE_EMPLEADO, npn.`DESCRIPCION_CARGO` AS CARGO, IF(ct.`FECHA_CONT_HA` = '99999999', 'INDEFINIDO', 'FIJO') AS TIPO_CONTRATO,\n " +
    "   ct.`FECHA_INGRESO` AS FECHA_INGRESO_CONTRATO, ct.`FECHA_CONT_HA` AS FECHA_CONTRATO_HASTA, CAST(ct.`SALARIO` AS UNSIGNED) AS SALARIO_CONTRATO, 'NULL' AS FECHA_CREACION_EMPLEADO,\n" +
    "   ct.`FECHA_RETIRO` AS FECHA_RETIRO, IF(sus.NOMBRES = tr.DESCRIPCION, 'SUSTITUCION', 'NORMAL') AS SUSTITUCION, IF(sus.FECHA_INGRESO = (NULL), ' ', sus.FECHA_INGRESO) AS FECHA_INGRESO_INSTITUCIONAL,\n" +
    "   (SELECT CAST(SUM(sal.`NMMOV_VALOR`) AS UNSIGNED) FROM NMRESUMEN_PAGOS_NOMINA sal WHERE sal.ID_TERC = npn.`ID_TERC` AND sal.ID_CPTO = '001' AND sal.LAPSO_DOC = npn.`LAPSO_DOC`) AS SALARIO,\n " +
    "   (SELECT CAST(SUM(sal.`NMMOV_VALOR`) AS UNSIGNED) FROM NMRESUMEN_PAGOS_NOMINA sal WHERE sal.ID_TERC = npn.`ID_TERC` AND sal.ID_CPTO IN ('002','003','004','008','009','010','011') AND sal.LAPSO_DOC = npn.`LAPSO_DOC`) AS HORAS_EXTRA \n" +
    "   FROM NMRESUMEN_PAGOS_NOMINA npn \n" +
    "   INNER JOIN TERCEROS tr \n" +
    "   ON tr.`CODIGO` = npn.`ID_TERC` \n" +
    "   INNER JOIN CONTRATOS ct \n" +
    "   ON ct.`ID_TERC` = tr.`CODIGO` \n" +
    "   LEFT JOIN SUSTITUCION_ANTIGUOS sus \n" +
    "   ON sus.`NOMBRES` = tr.`DESCRIPCION` \n" +
    "   INNER JOIN CONCEPTOS_NOMINA cn \n" +
    "   ON cn.CODIGO = npn.ID_CPTO \n" +
    "   WHERE \n" +
    "   npn.`LAPSO_DOC` ='"+obj.getLapso()+"' \n"+
    "   GROUP BY \n" +
    "   NOMBRE_EMPLEADO \n";
    rs = con.consultar(sql);
    return rs;
}
```

}

**Código de la clase que generará el archivo plano**

```
public class ControllerEscribir {
Calendar calendario = new GregorianCalendar();
String d = String.valueOf(calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
String M = String.valueOf(calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH));
String y = String.valueOf(calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR));
String s = String.valueOf(calendario.get(Calendar.SECOND));
String m = String.valueOf(calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
String H = String.valueOf(calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR));
String nombreArchivo = "CertificadosLaborales_"+y+M+d+"_"+H+m+s+".txt";
String datos;

public void crearArchivo(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{
    File f;
    f = new File(nombreArchivo);
    ResultSet rs2 = rs;
    try {
        FileWriter w = new FileWriter(f);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(w);
        PrintWriter salidaTexto = new PrintWriter(bw);
        while(rs2.next()){
            salidaTexto.write(rs2.getString("ID")+"|"+rs2.getString("COD_DOC")+"|"+
            rs2.getString("EMPLEADO")+"|"+rs2.getString("CONTRATO")+"|"+
            rs2.getString("EMPRESA")+"|"+rs2.getString("NOMBRE_EMPLEADO")+"|"+
            rs2.getString("CARGO")+"|"+rs2.getString("TIPO_CONTRATO")+"|"+
            rs2.getString("FECHA_INGRESO_CONTRATO")+"|"+rs2.getString("FECHA_CONTRATO_HASTA")+"|"+
            rs2.getString("SALARIO_CONTRATO")+"|"+rs2.getString("FECHA_CREACION_EMPLEADO")+"|"+
            rs2.getString("FECHA_RETIRO")+"|"+rs2.getString("SUSTITUCION")+"|"+rs2.getString("FECHA_INGRESO_INSTITUCIONAL")+"|"+
            rs2.getString("SALARIO")+"|"+rs2.getString("HORAS_EXTRA")+"\n");
        }

        salidaTexto.close();
        bw.close();
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ControllerEscribir.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

**Código clase conexión**

```
public class Conexion implements Configuracion{
    private static Connection con = null;

static {
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        if (con != null) {
            System.out.println("Conexion exitosa ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Conexion fallida");
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection() {
    return con;
}

public boolean ejecutar(String sql) {
    try {
        Statement sentencia;
        sentencia = getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        sentencia.executeUpdate(sql);
        sentencia.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public ResultSet consultar(String sql) {
    ResultSet resultado = null;
    try {
        Statement sentencia;
        sentencia = getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        resultado = sentencia.executeQuery(sql);       
        sentencia.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

}

Al empezar a correr el programa y darle el lapso determinado este me arroja dicho error el cual me indica estas líneas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si estoy saltando un paso o estoy haciendo uno de más..agradecería mucho la ayuda de ustedes para resolver este dilema.

Comment: La clase `Conexion` no es del API de Java, así que supongo que es tuya. Sin el código de `Conexion.consultar()` no se puede responder la pregunta -el resto parece correcto-; apuesto a que estás cerrando el `ResultSet`, bien directamente o con un `try-with-resources`.

Comment: Que por cierto, crear una clase `Conexion` sólo para hacer de wrapper a una `Connection` normalmente no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: Listo, añadí ya el código que me genera la conexión a la base de datos

Comment: La clase "Configuración" simplemente trae el nombre, usuario, contraseña y el driver de conexión a la Base de datos

Comment: Tengo la respuesta lista, pero veo que no te molestas en marcar como correctas las respuestas que recibes, así que la he borrado. Cuando vea que sigues la forma de funcionar del sitio, me plantearé volver a dejarla visible.

Comment: @SJuan76 En las 2 preguntas que he hecho en el sitio, sólo en una fue respondida como tal y ha sido la única a la cual pasé por alto el dejar la calificación de respuesta (La cual ya añadí como respuesta). La última que hice que fue sobre PHPExcel y qué poder hacer cuando el consumo de RAM evitaba que generará el archivo no fue respondida como tal, alguien sólo me dijo que me enseñaría a hacer un trabajo con XML pero la persona creo que se le olvidó.

Comment: Sencillamente quiero comentarte que el código tal y como lo tienes ahora es **totalmente vulnerable** a la Inyección SQL. Aparte de que el uso de PreparedStatement es más seguro, también es más rápido que el simple uso de Statement. Es **un buen concepto** tener una clase que maneje la.conexion a la BD, pero debe ser una clase que valga la pena, o sea, que use de la mejor manera el objeto conexión o las consultas enviadas a la BD, que cierre de forma correcta el resulset , la conexión etc. Si haces eso te evitarás este y otros problemas que podrían ser peores.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano, ya en este momento estoy organizando y leyendo un poco para reforzar más la seguridad de mi código de conexión. ¡Muchas gracias por el gran consejo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ResultSet consultar(String sql) {
    ResultSet resultado = null;
    try {
        Statement sentencia;
        sentencia = getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        resultado = sentencia.executeQuery(sql);       
        sentencia.close();//Aqui estas cerrando el statement
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

En el código que pongo arriba cierras el statement, por lo tanto el ResultSet que creaste con ese statement también se cierra. Por lo tanto cuando lo quieres usar tira la excepción porque ya esta cerrado:

```
public ResultSet obtenerCartas(ModelCartas_Laborales obj){
    ResultSet rs;
    sql = "SELECT ...";
    rs = con.consultar(sql);//Aqui llega cerrado
    return rs;
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, funciono perfectamente!. Ahora, mi pregunta va en si debo cerrar el ResultSet en donde realice la consulta? o en la clase de conexión como estaba antes?

Comment: Lo mejor es tener una clase que maneje las conexiones dotada de un método closeConnection el cual invocarás para cerrar la conexión. Esa misma clase será la encargada de crearte la conexión, de enviar las consultas a la BD usando consultas preparadas, de verificar si un registro existe, etc.